# What status checks can be used for GitHub organization rulesets

Tags: github, github-actions

When using branch protection on a repository, you can specify `Require status checks to pass before merging`. You can search for a job that is used by one of your workflows within the repository by typing to initiate the auto-complete.

Now, when using the new feature [GitHub Repository Rules](https://github.blog/2023-07-24-github-repository-rules-are-now-generally-available/), you have the option to set these up on an organizational level. In there you can roughly do the same as with branch protection but you can put it on a higher level.
The question is, when you setup the Repository ruleset on organization settings, what are you able to use as the status checks. From the organization's settings, I am talking about this menu:

[image: Repository rulesets menu item]

There does not seem to be an auto-complete feature, and I am able to type anything and add it via the plus button:

[image: Adding any status checks within repository rulesets]

So, I am wondering what we can add in here. The Repository ruleset that I currently have is set up for target "Select repositories". And I have for example a job called "build-api" which I am able to search for in the repository's branch protection:

[image: branch protection status check available]

This job is available in all of the selected repositories, so I might be able to add that name in there.
If I press the save button, I get the message `Ruleset updated` at the bottom left and when re-opening the ruleset, it still shows those non-existing status checks.

I checked [this documentation page](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets#require-status-checks-to-pass-before-merging) but that does not show much.

Also, I noticed in both of these discussion feedback's screenshot that the user gets a rounded rectangle in the search box which I don't seem to get:

- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/61107#discussioncomment-6752705
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/61107#discussioncomment-6562980

So, anyone a clue on what you can enter?